# How to disallow input when text fills the width and height of a textarea?

Tags: html, css

I need to use a textarea inside a div:

```
<div class="text-container">
    <textarea type="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

When i set the container to:

```
.text-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

for example and set the textarea to:

```
.text-container textarea {
    widht: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

the textarea will be as big as the div. the problem is i dont want a scroll or anything like it. if the text is filling the whole textarea i dont want to allow more text inputs.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: with html, you can't, really. put on some javascript and count characters or something.

Comment: what does this have to do with css? you're complaining that the css spatula won't solder your bathroom pipes. css is for styling.that has nothing to do with limiting characters entered into an input field.

Comment: yes, and css will make it 400x400 for you. whether that 400x400 contains the word "kittens" or the entire contents of "war and peace" is not css's problem.

Comment: You can set a `maxlength` to the textarea box (i.e., `<textarea maxlength="xx">`). Only thing other than that would be to use JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `maxlength` attribute combined with `resize: none;` and `overflow: hidden;`. The `maxlength` should be updated by javaScript when textarea is resized.

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea maxlength="160" placeholder="type max 160 characters"></textarea>
```

Comment: this won't be very reliable. What about the difference between an `i` and a `w`when it comes to width? And even if you would use a monospace font, your automatic line breaks could still mess things up. The only 100% solution would be js.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set resize to none for the textarea.

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

reference 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: That only stops it from resizing the textarea by dragging from bottom right corner.

Comment: There are several parts to this problem. This answer will address part of it. The other pieces are to add overflow:hidden style  (to disable scrolling) and use the "maxlength" attribute to prevent the user from typing further characters.

Answer (score -1):

Play with the overflow style:

```
style="overflow:hidden"
```

Comment: No, this will just disable the scroll bar but the user can still type after the words fill up the textarea, without being able to see the words..

Comment: It will work in combination with the "maxlength" attribute.